# Why is this Grep Expression not finding valid regex expression?

Tags: regex, grep

The regex expression below is for finding valid Amazon Cognito IdentityPool IDs with a test file but using the same expression with grep finds no valid matches yet the regex matches the test strings on https://regextester.com
Regex expression: `(us(-gov)?|ap|ca|cn|eu|sa)-(central|(north|south)?(east|west)?)-\d:[0-9a-f-]+` or even simplified like `[\w-]+:[0-9a-f-]+`.
Both fail for test strings like below yet are matched on Regextester.

```
us-west-1:de3e-e43-aeefe-bd
us-west-2:323-aaa33-a23d-dfe-daf
```

Running grep like:  `grep -oEarHn "(us(-gov)?|ap|ca|cn|eu|sa)-(central|(north|south)?(east|west)?)-\\d:[0-9a-f-]+" test.txt`

Comment: I think the `\\d` and `\d` should be `[0-9]`

Comment: Yep, that is PCRE.

Comment: See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/109046)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `\d` and `\\d` to `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` in your regular expression.

Default mode for grep id (iirc) POSIX regex. `\d` cames from PCRE. If you want to enable `\d`, you could add `-P` flag to grep. This enables perl-like regex, where `\d` is supported. Make sure, that you can't use `-E` and `-P` flags at the same time.

Comment: There are multiple POSIX regex dialects; `grep` by definition uses BRE, but the OP uses `grep -E` which switches to the ERE dialect. The `-P` option is nonstandard, and only works in GNU `grep`.

Comment: @tripleee, you have right. I have improved my answer.